# postgres hba.conf for jdbc

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, configuration, tcp, ssh

I'm trying to set up a JDBC connection to postgres from another program.

When I run the program, I get the following error:

[2013-03-24 03:14:10,542][ERROR][org.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverSource] while opening read connection: jdbc:postgresql://[my postgres server's ip address]:5432/[my database name] FATAL: **no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my client ip address]", user "postgres", database "[my database name]", SSL off**

I can connect to the server successfully with a command line client by running:
psql -d [my database name] -U postgres -p 5432 -h [my postgres server ip address]

I think then that I have a unix socket connection that works but need to enable tcp connection in the pg_hba.conf, but it looks like I already have several tcp connections allowed in the pg_hba.conf file below... can anyone advise what I may be doing wrong?

My pg_hba.conf contains the following uncommented lines:

```
hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all all 10.0.0.0/8 md5
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If doing devel on local computer and booth program and DB run on the same machine go with:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Comment: It's a remote host on amazon ec2; security group is configured to allow all traffic through port 5432... do you think like hostnossl all all 0.0.0.0/0 would work? not very sure how to set up this file :o

Comment: for the record, the following worked for me: I copied my client ip address into the slot and added a host record with option trust. I'll accept your answer since you had the trust option listed :p

Comment: just change ip address and mask in record i have wrote. doesn't have experience with amazon ec2 but changind ip address to your ip address should work